Understanding how much zoom can be used in post on Insta360 before quality suffers
Starting my videography journey with a Insta360 One X2.
Something which is mystifying for me is how far in I can zoom in post production before I lose quality at a given output resolution.
So the Insta360 Studio software has a concept of FoV and Distortion Control.  Both of these effect the zoom of the final output.
When the intended output is lets say 1080p, there must be some formula based on the resolution of the original footage, where exceeding a combination of FoV and DC results in the reframed output image being zoomed in past what the camera actually captured.
The raw resolution for my footage is 5760x2880.
The field of view is also represented as a angle.  So if my output format is 9:16, 1080x1920 how far in can I bring the image before I am "over zoomed".

The right answer is try it and see. In general I try to not scale above 120% in conventional video

Detail loss will occur as a function of the inverse square law.  That is, a 2X zoom level will result in a 4X loss of quality. A 3X zoom level results in 9X quality loss, etc.
